# PDE weak form and FEM approximation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I need to derive the weak form for the following PDE system:

$\rho_{f}\frac{\partial \mathbf{u}}{\partial t}+\nabla P=0$ in $\Omega_{s}$

$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u}=0$ in $\Omega_{s}$

where $P=P(x,y,t):\mathbb{R^+}\times \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , 
$\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}(x,y,t):\mathbb{R^+}\times \mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$
are both unknowns.

The boundary conditions are the following:

$P=\bar{P}$ on $\Gamma^{1}_{f}\cup \Gamma^{2}_{f}$

$\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{n}=0$ on $\Gamma^{3}_{f}$

$\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{n}=w$ on $\Gamma$

An illustration of the computation domain can be seen here $\rightarrow$[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0w3M.png).

I try to multiply by the test function and integrating, but then I don't see how I can go from there, because I can't seem to determine both $P$ and $\mathbf{u}$ with only these two equations after approximating with linear finite elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have the case of a mixed finite element problem. This a special case of time-dependent Stoke's equation. You need to use a pair of finite elements that will solve these equations. I suggest reading Mixed FEM for Stokes equation to get an idea of how to do the problem. NOTE: You have $\partial u/\partial t$, i.e., you have to apply a finite difference to approximate the time derivative